# when i click on delete button next image is deleted not the image i clicked in php mysql image gallery

Tags: php, mysql

form to upload images

```
 <form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <input type='file' name='file'>
 <input type='submit' value='Upload'>
 </form>
```

php coding to insert and display image gallery from database session created to store id of the image to delete

```
<?php 
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","img") or die ("connection failed ");
if ($_FILES)
{
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$insert = "insert into image (image) values ('".$name."')";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,$insert);
}
$view = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from image");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($view))
{   
extract($row);
echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"del\" value=\"submit\"></form><a href=\"$image\"><img src=\"$image\" /></a>";
if(isset($_POST['del']))
{   
$_SESSION['del_id'] = $id;
header("location:del.php");
}
}
?>
```

del.php  session id will be deleted

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","img") or die ("connection failed ");
$id = $_SESSION['del_id'];
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"delete from image where id = '$id' ");
header("location:x.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you are getting the `id` value from to set `del_id.` However, you would need something like this:

replace:

```
 echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"del\" value=\"submit\"></form><a href=\"$image\"><img src=\"$image\" /></a>";
```

With this:

```
echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"del\" value=\"submit\">";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"del_id\" value=\"$row['id']\">";
echo "</form>";
echo "<a href=\"$image\"><img src=\"$image\" /></a>";
```

And change `$_SESSION['del_id'] = $id;` to `$_SESSION['del_id'] = $_POST['del_id'];`

Comment: sorry i extract the row values but i missed that line

Comment: I have a feeling that what I did will what you will need.  But update your original post so we can take a look.

Comment: extract wont work, because you need the row that's tied to the respective delete button. Test the code I provided.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\x.php on line 48

Comment: If it works for you then please click the 'check mark' next to the answer so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$_SESSION['del_id'] = $id;
```

Where do you fetch this $id ?

Comment: That should be posted as a comment not an answer

Comment: I know, I don't have enough rep yet :( Sorry

Comment: please check my new coding i missed that line while editing